# Перебор многомерного массива в php без рекурсии

Tags: php

Задан многомерный массив такого вида:

```
$data = [
    [
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => test,
        "childs" => [
            "id" => 4,
            "name" => test 2,
            "childs" => [
                ...
            ]
        ]
    ],
    ...
];
```

Мне нужно производить некоторые модификации над этим массивом, для этого требуется перебирать все элементы массива и делать нужные проверки.

Хотелось бы реализовать без рекурсии. Подскажите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты для этого?

Я предполагаю делать как-то так:

```
$currentArData = $arData;

foreach($currentArData as $currentData) {

    ...

    if(isset($currentData["childs"]))
        $currentArData = $currentData["childs"];

}
```

Но в этом случае, цикл будет ходить по вложенности только в глубину..

Comment: Тебе ж пофиг, в каком порядке - лишь бы обработать? Значит, ничто не запрещает обработать запись текущего левела. а потом рекурсировать внутрь. А хвостовая рекурсия легко преобразуется в нерекурсивный, итеративный, код...

Comment: проверять текущий эл-та на `is_array()` вместо `isset($currentData["childs"])` и делать что надо дальше

Comment: Порядок обхода к сожалени важен. Т.е. приоритет обхода в глубину.

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf было бы понятно какой оптимизации вы хотите добиться видя примерный исходный массив и результат выполнения который вы хотели бы увидеть

Comment: чем вас вообще не устраивает рекурсия?

Comment: Рекурсия не устраивает тем, что это должен быть метод класса.
А решая задачу, нужно хранить много информации о родительских элементах, и предыдущих нодов. Глобальные свойства из-за 1 метода, или статические переменные не хочу городить.

Comment: Все же думаю рекурсия будет лучшим выходом. Нужную информацию можно хранить в свойствах класса. Плюс модифицировать массив, по которому идет обход не очень хорошо.

Comment: `Глобальные свойства из-за 1 метода, или статические переменные не хочу городить.`. Ээээ... зачем глобальные? Можно передавать детей как параметр метода.

Comment: внутри метода анонимку рекурсивную напишите и все. вообще никаких изменений в класс не надо вносить.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php, https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.recursivearrayiterator.php

Comment: teran, можно пример пожалуйста?